# Polymorphism test not working

Tags: c++, polymorphism

The following code does not compile, but I cannot understand the error:

```
#include <iostream>

class FamilyMember {

    int age;
    public:
    virtual int myage () = 0;
};


class Grandfather: public FamilyMember {

    int age;
    public:
    Grandfather (): age(60) {
        std::cout << "Im grandpa" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Grandfather () {
        std::cout << "Oh no! Grandpa is dead!" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual int myage () const {
        return age;
    }
};


class Father: public Grandfather {

    int age;
    public:
    Father (): age(40) {
        std::cout << "Im papa" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Father () {
        std::cout << "Papa is gone, noooooo!" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual int myage () const {
        return age;
    }
};


class Son: public Father {

    int age;
    public:
    Son (): age(20) {
        std::cout << "Im the kid" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Son () {
        std::cout << "Son is dead? He was so young!" << std::endl;
    }
    int myage () const {
        return age;
    }
};

int main () {

    Grandfather G;
    Father F;
    Son S;

   return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors I get (I cut down the code to the minimum amount that breaks it, so the line numbers will not match).

```
main.cc:535: error: cannot declare variable ‘G’ to be of abstract type ‘Grandfather’
main.cc:161: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Grandfather’:
main.cc:157: note:  virtual int FamilyMember::myage()
main.cc:536: error: cannot declare variable ‘F’ to be of abstract type ‘Father’
main.cc:177: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Father’:
main.cc:157: note:  virtual int FamilyMember::myage()
main.cc:537: error: cannot declare variable ‘S’ to be of abstract type ‘Son’
main.cc:193: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Son’:
main.cc:157: note:  virtual int FamilyMember::myage()
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that a Grandfather and a Father actually have _two_ members called age? One inherited from FamilyMember and their own?

Comment: So I should then not have `int age` on `FamilyMember`? Technically, from what you said, `Father` should have **three** members called age then. One from its own, one from `Grandfather` and one from `Familymember`, no?

Comment: Right. What you should do depends on what you're trying to achieve. I don't see the point in this inheritance relationship. Every family member has an age and that's the only attribute you have. So, why bother creating this inheritance relatonship? Don't overuse inheritance.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out. I'm for now just trying to learn the concept of polymorphism but your suggestion will definitely help me in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different signatures.

```
virtual int myage () = 0;
```

And in child classes.

```
virtual int myage () const
```

Make `pure-virtual` `myage` `const` too, or make `non-const` this function in childs.

Comment: Thank you. Now, if I wanted to print the age of `Father` from a `Son` object, how do I do it? Basically my question is: how do I call the function `myage()` of `Father` from a `Son` object?

Comment: @curvature Father::myage() in function of Son object.

Comment: And what if I have a function `void PrintMyAge(const FamilyMember* f) { std::cout << f->myage() << std::endl; }` and on main I had `Son s`. How do I call `PrintMyAge(s)` in such a way to print actually the age of a father?

Comment: I tried this: `Father* pF = dynamic_cast<Father*>(&s)`, where `s` is a `Son` object, but when I do `std::cout << "pf->myage() = " << pF->myage() << std::endl;`, the result is still 20. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @curvature you can use this std::cout << f->Father::myage() << std::endl; but why you need such things?

Comment: I'm just trying to learn the concepts. I want to convert an object of type `Son` to a type `Father` so that when I send the converted object to a function, the values of `Father` will be used instead of the values of `Son`. I had already tried your last suggestion and it worked, but it's not what I really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said in all the other answers, C++11 provides the special identified `override` which would have pointer out the error at compile time:

```
class Grandfather: public FamilyMember {

    // as before ...

    virtual int myage () const override {  // Error! Not overriding.
        return age;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not overriding `myage` correctly.

`virtual int myage () = 0;`

is not the same thing as

`virtual int myage () const`

The `const` on the method will make it a different signature, and thus a different method

Answer (score 0):

This is declared pure virtual in the base

```
 virtual int myage () = 0;
```

but in the derived class the function prototype is

```
 virtual int myage () const
```

this is a different function and so your non-const version in the base class has not been overridden, and the compiler error is telling you this.

Answer (score 0):

Function myage in class "FamilyMember" and "Grandfather" has different signature.

virtual int myage () = 0; // In FamilyMember

and

virtual int myage () const // In Grandfather

Try changing definition of class FamilyMember as follows 
    class FamilyMember {

```
int age;
public:
virtual int myage () const = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it would make more sense not to give each subclasses an `age` attribute, just use the one, the superclass has.

```
class FamilyMember
{
    protected:
        int age;
    public:
        virtual int myage ()  const = 0;
        FamilyMember(int a) : age(a) {}
};

class Grandfather: public FamilyMember
{
    public:
        Grandfather (): FamilyMember(60) {}
        ~Grandfather () {}
        virtual int myage () const { return FamilyMember::age; }
};
```